# <content> tag inside <style> tags for templates?

Tags: css, html, web-component, html5-template

I am writing a demo of Web Components, and my markup is structured like this:

```
<a-component>
    <the-color>red</the-color>
</a-component>
```

In my `<template>` tag for `<the-color>`, I need it to apply `background-color: <any color>` for `<a-component>`. Here's what I have so far:

```
<style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
      }
</style>
```

How do I make it take "red" from `<content>` and make it apply `background-color: red` to `<a-component>`? Also, I'm using Shadow DOM to insert the template into the page, via run-time Javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `<content>` tag is the best way to extract a string from the DOM to set a CSS rule.

Instead you can use directly `this.querySelector('the-color').textContent` in the `createdCallback` method of your custom element:

```
document.registerElement( 'a-component', { 
    prototype: Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype, {
        createdCallback: {
            value: function () 
            {
                var root = this.createShadowRoot()
                root.appendChild( document.importNode( template.content, true ) )
                this.style.backgroundColor = this.querySelector( 'the-color' ).textContent
            }
        }
    } )
} )
```

---

But if you want to get the value via a `<content>` inside the `<template>`, you can use the `getDistributedNodes` method:

```js
document.registerElement('a-component', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
    createdCallback: {
      value: function() {
        //apply template to Shadow DOM
        var root = this.createShadowRoot()
        root.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true))
        
        //select the content tag, then get the inserted node
        var content = root.querySelector('content[select=the-color]')
        var nodes = content.getDistributedNodes()
        
        //apply the content of the first node to the style's property
        color = nodes[0].textContent
        this.style.backgroundColor = color
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<template id='template'>
  I'm a <content select='the-color'></content> component
</template>
<a-component>
  <the-color>red</the-color>
</a-component>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to do it with CSS, but this is okay. Also, can you explain why you need to use the `getDistributedNodes` method?

Comment: Because the element you want to reach, `<the-color>`, is not part of the Shadow DOM, you cannot select it via `querySelector`. To achieve it WebComponents provides  the `content.getDistributedNodes` method. It permits to access the elements inserted via `<content>` tags.

Comment: Thanks! I was really confused